# Screen Resolution Detect

Tags: javascript

how can i put option in WordPress theme if someone visit my site then header or sidebar showing they are Screen Resolution auto detect how can i add

[screen link](http://myprintscreen.com/s/vb6p/ee00bf3caa)

[link here](https://wallpapershome.com/nature/mountains/yosemite-5k-4k-wallpaper-desert-sand-osx-apple-sunset-170.html)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use JavaScript. To get the width and height of the screen:

```
<script>
    var height = window.screen.height;
    var width = window.screen.width;
</script>
```

To properly take into account higher resolution devices, like Apple's 'retina' displays you will want to multiply those values by the 'pixel ratio':

```
<script>
    var pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio;
    var height = window.screen.height * pixelRatio;
    var width = window.screen.width * pixelRatio;
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, ok dear so how can i add this into my single.php file or what i do? thanks